# C++ port of .NET libraries

Tags: c++, .net

Is there a C++ "port" of .NET library, in the sense that the library class and methods correspond? At least some of them? Like System.Xml, System.Net?

Comment: Is there any reason you don't want to use C++/CLI? The libraries are really designed with the .NET framework in mind - what's idiomatic within .NET wouldn't necessarily be idiomatic in a non-.NET environment.

Comment: I agree with the idiomatism part, I am just wondering if there is such a native wrapper that does not rely on the .NET Framework, but may help .NET programmer to get things done a little quicker.

Comment: That sounds like *short-term* gain at the expense of long-term maintainability. If you're going to buy into moving away from .NET, you should do so wholeheartedly, IMO. Take the time to learn the idioms of whatever specific platform libraries you're going to use, rather than trying to speak "C++ with a .NET accent".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have a mixed code solution whic contains pure c++ code and c++ cli code. Assuming of course that you are interested only in windows os.

Comment: I have posted this from phone, apologies for the style ;)

Comment: Thanks, i am just trying my luck at a non .NET implementation.